# How to do mariadb setup(version 10.2.17) with entity framework 6(web api) using ADO.net Identity data model in visual studio 2015?

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, mariadb

Currently wizard is silently  getting closed, I am using  MySQL connector/net, and in providers I have used entity framework 6.0.0, mysql.data 6.9.12,mysql.data.entity and mysql.web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[MySQL EF 8.0.13][1]
[Advanced options][2]
[Set port][3]
```

Get the MySQL 8.0.13 adapters for VS and don't use the 6.x.x.
This should solve the EF selection window from crashing.

```
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j49nq.png
```

If you can't connect to your server with the connector, be sure to fill in the port to your DB.

```
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OlEdq.png

  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IONuS.png
```